# Run a docker command within a container managed by tilt

Tags: kubernetes, tilt

In my node project, I would like to define a script in my `package.json` file like:

```
{
    "scripts": {
        "runTestsWithTilt": "<some command to run tests within a container launched by tilt>"
    }
}
```

Is there a `tilt` cli command where I could run an arbitrary command through `docker exec`?

Something like: `tilt docker exec <container-name> <command-to-run>`

Answer (score -1):

Tilt is still developing and the [documentation](https://docs.tilt.dev/cli/tilt_docker.html) is very minimal, in the official [documentation](https://docs.tilt.dev/cli/tilt_docker.html) and in the [official github page](https://github.com/tilt-dev/tilt) they have mentioned only a syntax for executing docker commands but they didn’t provide a complete manual anywhere. So for now, similar to KinD (Kubernetes in Docker) we need to use docker commands for a few operations. Hope this will be addressed soon.

Comment: The question is how to do the docker command to connect to a pod in the cluster and run arbitrary command

Comment: @coler-j if you want to write a code then you can use this [TiltFile api](https://docs.tilt.dev/api.html#api.docker_build) reference documentation here they are mentioning about various arguments out of which you can use the container_args("https://docs.tilt.dev/api.html#api.docker_build:~:text=flag.-,container_args,-(") for connecting to your container.